# load time is really pathatic

Tags: opencart, pagespeed

I am working on an opencart project with the url [www.prabhukrishna.com](http://www.prabhukrishna.com) , my  version of Opencart is `V2.3.0.2` with a Journal theme `V2.8.3`. Every thing is Working but the page load speeds are slow. I have tested in `GTMetrix` and it shows the load time 56 seconds however in `Pingdom` it shows the time around 5-6 seconds.

I am really nervous about the page load time if it is 56 sec. On the live version I am not getting any issues with the load time on my browser. It seems around 2-3 seconds.

Any suggestion? Is journal theme a very heavy theme which can slow down opencart?

Comment: Journal is indeed a very heavy theme which relies a great deal on their own classes instead of Opencart's core.  That said, it shouldn't be anywhere close to 56 seconds.  How many products you have?  Product counting queries and poorly indexed db tables are the two most common things to slow things own from my experience.

Comment: the site has just 10 products. Its strange that pingdom shoes load time 3-4 seconds but gtmetrix shoes above 50 seconds. what can be the issue ?

Comment: can you suggest any clean responsive theme rather that journal. But journal has huge customization control.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that your site has a lot of content to download on the first visit, i.e. style sheets, JavaScript, images etc. Once this has downloaded then it will likely be cached locally casing the quick(er) load time.

Try clearing your browser cache and reloading the site, if that first load takes a long time then its getting a lot of content.

You can use the network tab in the Firebug extension (Chrome and Firefox) to see what files are being downloaded, you might be better using the Google page speed tool if your not familiar with Firebug as that will also tell you what you need to do (to some degree).

The idea would be to minify the css/js (saves space), lower image quality to make them smaller and also ensure that content is not being loaded on pages that dont need it. Finally, check that your not setting modules to display hundreds of products (i.e the featured items module). Set these to max 25 items.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easiest solution is to compress your images.  If you don't have Photoshop then I would suggest using GIMP (free).